# Power BI Report Table group by count result of a column

Tags: powerbi, dax, report

I need to count the frequency and the no. of users per frequency of logins. I was able to achieve the result of all years, however, the counts are not correct if I do the filter on "Years" and "Login via" column. It also counts the frequency on other years. I think the problem is with the relationship of the table with group by and the raw table. I created a group by UserName table, count(LoginRef). I linked the raw table and group by table, by UserName. which is the reason why the result is incorrect if I filter other columns.

Raw Data:

| Date | UserName | LoginRef | Login via |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/18/2022 | user5 | 1 | mobile |
| 06/18/2022 | user6 | 2 | browser |
| 07/15/2022 | user7 | 3 | app |
| 07/15/2023 | user1 | 4 | app |
| 07/15/2023 | user2 | 5 | mobile |
| 07/16/2023 | user3 | 6 | browser |
| 07/16/2023 | user4 | 7 | mobile |
| 07/17/2023 | user4 | 8 | app |
| 07/17/2023 | user5 | 9 | app |
| 07/17/2023 | user6 | 10 | mobile |
| 07/18/2023 | user7 | 11 | browser |

**Results:**

**All Years:**

| Login Frequency | No. of Users |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

**Filter: 2022**

| Login Frequency | No. of Users |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |

**Filter: 2023**

| Login Frequency | No. of Users |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 |

**My group by table:**

| UserName | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | 1 |
| user2 | 1 |
| user3 | 1 |
| user4 | 2 |
| user5 | 2 |
| user6 | 2 |
| user7 | 2 |

I have also tried creating a column with concatenated values of the filters. However, the counts for all years gets doubled for some users. I have tried many different approach and still unsuccessful.